# Get system property from BeanShell Sampler in setup Thread Group

Tags: jmeter

I have a setup thread group and I am trying to access a system property. Currently I have the following in my BeanShell...

```
String filename = System.getenv().get("server.portal.articleFile");
System.out.println(filename);
```

I have also tried...

```
String filename = props.get("server.portal.articleFile");
```

All of these seem to output null. When I check the debug sampler I see the `server.portal.articleFile` property set correctly under system properties.

How do I access these system properties from a beanshell sampler in a setup thread group.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work...

```
import org.apache.jmeter.util.JMeterUtils;
String filename = JMeterUtils.getProperty("server.portal.articleFile");
```